# Return all rows where at least one value in any of the columns is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have just completed the process of loading new tables with data. I'm currently trying to validate the data. The way I have designed my database there really shouldn't be any values anywhere that are `NULL` so i'm trying to find all rows with any `NULL` value.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this instead of writing a lengthy `WHERE` clause with `OR` statements checking each column?

UPDATE: A little more detail... `NULL` values are valid initially as sometimes the data is missing. It just helps me find out what data I need to hunt down elsewhere. Some of my tables have over 50 columns so writing out the whole `WHERE` clause is not convenient.

Comment: You are going to have to address every column one way or another. There just isn't any way around that.

Comment: If you are using this querying in conjunction with a web platform, such as php or asp you should be able to query the table schema and dynamically build a query that way. As for not using OR statements, I'm not sure how you would do that.

Comment: Implementing all columns as `NOT NULL` suggests itself... otherwise, you are going to have to specify every column by name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a query against `Information_Schema.Columns` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)) that outputs the SQL for your very long where clause.

Here's something to get you started:

```
select 'OR ([' + TABLE_NAME + '].[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] IS NULL)'
from mydatabase.Information_Schema.Columns
order by TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: This method is easy to understand and definitely less time consuming than writing `IS NOT NULL` for 50+ columns in a `WHERE`. Thanks!

Comment: A little clarification. What is it that is supposed to go in `TABLE__SCHEMA` in this example code?

Comment: @Indoordinosaur I don't really understand the question. TABLE_SCHEMA (only one underscore, not two) isn't a placeholder. It's an actual column of the `Information_Schema.Columns` view.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought `TABLE_SCHEMA` was a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

The short version answer, use SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON and bung the whole thing together as a string and check that for NULL (once). That way any null will propagate through to make the whole row comparison null.

Here's the silly sample code to demo the principal, up to you if you want to wrap that in an auto-generating schema script (to only check Nullable columns and do all the appropriate conversions). Efficient it ain't, but almost any way you cut it you will need to do a table scan anyway.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example
(
PK INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
A nchar(10) NULL,
B int NULL,
C nvarchar(50) NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT dbo.Example(A, B, C)
VALUES('Your Name', 1, 'Not blank'),
('My Name', 3, NULL),
('His Name', NULL, 'Not blank'),
(NULL, 5, 'It''s blank');

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON 
SELECT E.PK 
FROM dbo.Example E
WHERE (E.A + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), E.B) + E.C) IS NULL
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
```

Comment: This isn't such a bad approach, but the problem is that it becomes prohibitive if you're trying to check lots of tables with lots of columns.

Comment: Prohibitive in the sense of what? As I said - any way you cut it will be a table scan. Because, you're checking the whole table. Even checking just 10-20% will most likely end in table scan. And, "efficient" wasn't part of the question. And, it was to avoid WHERE .. OR .. OR .. OR. OK that's pretty dumb, but again it was in the question.

Comment: Prohibitive on the developer/DBA to write that query for each table in the database - there's no real way to get this kind of thing to not be awful in terms of query performance.  If I have a table with 100 columns, I have to type out all 100 columns in that where clause - and I have to do that for each table...

Comment: Read the answer, again. The short version answer was followed by "up to you if you want to wrap that in an auto-generating schema script". 'Nough said.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think the auto-generating part is probably what the asker is having a bigger issue with :)

Comment: I know which is going to be easier for someone to remember and code in a hurry. A combination of exec sp_help [dbo.Example] and CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL? OK, better if you have those kinds of schema-generation scripts to hand to hack about. But, sometimes, I just simply don't.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, if you really expect columns to not be null, then put `NOT NULL` constraints on them.  That said...

Here's a slightly different approach, using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'UNION ALL SELECT ''' + cnull.TABLE_NAME + ''' as TableName, ''' 
                                           + cnull.COLUMN_NAME + ''' as NullColumnName, '''
                                           + pk.COLUMN_NAME + ''' as PkColumnName,' +
                                           + 'CAST(' + pk.COLUMN_NAME + ' AS VARCHAR(500)) as PkValue '
                                           + ' FROM ' + cnull.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + cnull.TABLE_NAME 
                                           + ' WHERE ' +cnull.COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cnull
INNER JOIN (SELECT Col.Column_Name, col.TABLE_NAME, col.TABLE_SCHEMA
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
                ON  Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
                WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY') pk
ON pk.TABLE_NAME = cnull.TABLE_NAME AND cnull.TABLE_SCHEMA = pk.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE cnull.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'

set @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 11, LEN(@sql)) -- remove the initial 'UNION ALL '

exec(@sql)
```

Rather a huge where clause, this will tell you the primary key on the table where any field in that table is null.  Note that I'm `CAST`ing all primary key values to avoid operand clashes if you have some that are `int`/`varchar`/`uniqueidentifier` etc.  If you have a PK that doesn't fit into a `VARCHAR(500)` you probably have other problems....

This would probably need some tweaking if you have any tables with composite primary keys - as it is, I'm pretty sure it would just output separate rows for each member of the key instead of concatenating them, and wouldn't necessarily group them together the way you'd want.

One other thought would be to just `SELECT *` from ever table and save the output to a format (Excel, plain text csv) you can easily search for the string `NULL`.